# how to get the side of collide body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, cocos2d-x, physics

i am using box2d for bouncing the ball the problem arises that ball only bounce in vertical direction when user press left and right i change the position off the ball it working fine. Problem arises whenever it hit the block i set the velocity like (0,5) so if ball hit from top of block it bounce back and its fine but also when moving the ball horizontally ball hit the left or right side and at that point i dont need to set the velocity so how i achieve this in a nutshell i want to detect which side of the block ball hit in contact listner

Comment: Maybe you could use the contact manifold information to decide which side was hit. This might help: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy

Comment: During contact event, you have access to both bodies, you can then determine their positions relative to each other. An alternative is to use sensor bodies at either side, or ray casting.

Comment: will u please explain me with some code

Comment: i try to implement b2WorldManifold but dont work properly

Comment: any one knows the solution?